# Put an array into a Hashmap as a key or a value using curly braces doesn't work

Tags: java, arrays, char, hashmap

Why this is possible

```
   Map <char[],char[]>F = new HashMap<char[],char[]>();
   char []R = {'J','K','L'};
   char []X = {'J','L'};
   F.put(R,X);
```

while this is not

```
   Map <char[],char[]>F = new HashMap<char[],char[]>();
   F.put({'J','K','L'}, {'J','L'});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct syntax for the second example is:

```
F.put(new char[]{'J','K','L'}, new char[]{'J','L'});
```

When you use `{'J', 'K', 'L'}` outside an initializer, the compiler doesn't try to guess the type of the array. You have to state it explicitly.

Also note that, since `array1.equals(array2)` compares *the addresses* of two arrays, your `HashMap` will behave in ways you'll probably find surprising. Consider:

```
    Map<char[], char[]> F = new HashMap<char[], char[]>();
    F.put(new char[] { 'J', 'K', 'L' }, new char[] { 'J', 'L' });
    F.put(new char[] { 'J', 'K', 'L' }, new char[] { 'J', 'L' });
    System.out.println(F.size());
```

On my machine, this prints `2` even though the two keys consist of exactly the same characters.

Comment: You said it's "surprising" that the size of the 'HashMap' is 2,is this because `HashMap` doesn't keep identical entries?

Comment: @yannishristofakis: The two keys look exactly the same, yet both are preserved.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible -

```
Map <char[],char[]>F = new HashMap<char[],char[]>();
F.put(new char[]{'J','K','L'}, new char[]{'J','L'});
```

`{'J', 'K', 'L'}` is an anonymous array without type which cause syntax mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

{'J', ...} is not how you declare anonymous array, you have to explicitly declare the type that your array holds.

you probably want

```
    Map <char[],char[]>F = new HashMap<char[],char[]>();
       F.put(new char[]{'J','K','L'}, new char[]{'J','L'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to **explicitly specify type of the operands** as:

```
Map <char[],char[]>F = new HashMap<char[],char[]>();
F.put(new char []{'J','K','L'}, new char []{'J','L'});
```

and this will work.